# noun phrase as an adjective

Tags: nouns, adjectives, compound-adjectives

We know that a noun phrase contains at least a noun or a pronoun and for the most part, these phrases can be replaced by a pronoun.

Ex: "We spoke to *[the old guy that lives in the little shed on the last farm to the left.]*

I made that example long just to illustrate the potential of a noun phrase.

But what about this?

I already spoke to *[the good-for-nothing slob.]*

Is "good for nothing" modifying slob as an adjective?

If so, is the entire phrase an adjectival phrase within a noun phrase?

Comment: Anything hyphenated is a single compound word. So _good-for-nothing_ is an adjective, but not a phrase. If it followed _slob_ instead of preceding it, it would be a phrase and wouldn't be hyphenated: _a slob good for nothing_, which is short for a relative clause _a slob (that/who is) good for nothing_ that's been reduced to a phrase by _Whiz_-Deletion.

Comment: "the good-for-nothing slob" is a ***noun phrase*** with three parts: determiner (*the*) + adjective (*good-for-nothing*) + noun (*slob*)

Comment: ok, so far im getting that it is a compound word and since it is hylhenated it acts as a single word.  On e person is tellig me it is an adjective, the other is saying it is a noun phrase...are both answers right?

Comment: I take it back. The entire statement is a noun lhrase meanwhile "goodfornothing" would be the compund word acting as an adjective.

Comment: Sounds like you got it!

Answer (score 1):

> Anything hyphenated is a single compound word. So *good-for-nothing* is an adjective, but not a phrase. If it followed *slob* instead of preceding it, it would be a phrase and wouldn't be hyphenated: *a slob good for nothing*, which is short for *a relative clause a slob (that/who is) good for nothing* that's been reduced to a phrase by *Whiz*-Deletion. – John Lawler